# HFS+ drive mounting issues

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, hfs+

I'm looking to access data on an external hard drive which is formatted in the HFS+ format (created from/for a mac). After some initial difficulties (and confusion over what format the drive is actually in) I installed the HFS+ driver and everything worked fine. However, after I unplugged the drive and then tried to access the data again a while later, I'm once again getting the error along the lines of "protocol driver not attached" and the drive won't mount. Aside from a reboot probably fixing the issue, I'm not exactly sure why the HFS+ driver would stop working every time I unplug the drive. Has anyone had this issue before, or know of any way to go about fixing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.